# Is it possible to autoinstall ubuntu desktop just like the server version?

Tags: server, system-installation, usb, automation

I have a ubuntu desktop that I also use as a CI/CD server on my home. I always break stuff so I wanted to have a USB stick that auto installs everything.

https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall is for server only.

Is there a way to autoinstall the desktop version as easy as the server version, without having to code? I found some self made solutions but I wanted the autoinstall one just like the server version of ubuntu.

Comment: You've not provided any release details, but there is a *canary* desktop installer that is based on the `subiquity` server installer so it may provide the identical functionality as it does on server systems (that's the intention; but you gave no specifics on release).  There is some auto-config on `ubiquity` installer, but again without specifics how it compares depends on details you didn't provide (*recent releases offered both though the canary installer is still a work-in-progress so not as stable on it is on server*)

Comment: @guiverc don't think so. The autoinstall afaik is for servers only atm. Rafaelo "without having to code?" whatever version you find code you shall. It is totally based on a yaml setup so you will need to understand yaml's json style.  I is FAR easier to use a normal desktop and execute a post-install script (a script that holds all the actions you execute to get where you want: add/remove packages, setttings (gsettings) you set). You canalso make a backup of (config) files you edit and cp them after install

Comment: I wanted to not need to put username, password, etc so a post install script would not be the best.