# Automatic/unattended installation of Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox, virtualization, ubuntu-mate

I would like to provide to my students a Virtual Machine several software pre-installed. The software is updated quite regularly so an automated way to generate a VM would be very useful. I plan to use the MATE edition of Ubuntu 22.04 . I am wondering if  there is any preseed template for this version available?

So far I use VirtualBox as VM software, but a solution with other VM manager (like qemu) would still be useful, as I probably can convert the image to the VirtualBox format in a later step.

I found this [short documentation about Ubiquity Automation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbiquityAutomation) and `ubiquity/success_command` sounds promising, but it is unclear to me where to put this command.

[My question is similar to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1422073/is-it-possible-to-autoinstall-ubuntu-desktop-just-like-the-server-version). But unlike the previous question, it is ok for me to code.]

Comment: Why do you say "this option is no longer possible"?  My understanding is that the 22.04 Desktop Installer still uses Ubiquity (which is based on debian-installer) and can be automated with a preseed file.  If you dig around there are a few Questions on this site about using the server installer to install a desktop system.  E.g. https://askubuntu.com/a/1292033/376778

Comment: Perhaps clone the modified OS to an image file, (.img), and then convert that to VDI for distribution? see: https://www.unixmen.com/linux-basics-convert-img-files-to-vdi-format-for-oracle-virtualbox/

Comment: @AndrewLowther Thanks a lot! Indeed, preseed should still be possible. I got confused with the Desktop/Server installation routines. I will update my question.

Comment: It's still nice to know how to dispatch an unattended installation of Ubuntu 22.04 desktop, specifying e.g. minimal installation, install updates while installing and do the default disk partitioning. The link provided above seems to be specific to network installation and speaks less of automate the desktop installation so that no GUI questions are asked during the install.